# Adjektivforme bei mehreren Substantiven von verschiedenen Genus

Tags: adjective, gender, list

> Eine kaputte Uhr mit gebrochenem Gesperr und gebrochener Feder.

klingt umständlich.
Kann man das zweite "gebrochener" auslassen?

> Eine kaputte Uhr mit gebrochenem Gesperr und Feder.

Das würde grammatikalisch nicht stimmen, aber wäre es möglich?
Oder verwendet man von Anfang an Plural?

> Eine kaputte Uhr mit gebrochenen Gesperr und Feder.

Comment: Eine kaputte Uhr, deren Gesperr und Feder gebrochen sind.

Comment: *Liebe Anna und Tom!" in einer Briefanrede: Tom ist anscheinend nicht lieb. Oder "Suche junge Mitarbeiterin oder Mitarbeiter" in einer Stellenanzeige. Männer würden sie auch alte nehmen...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Eigentlich nicht, die zweite Variante schon gar nicht. Man könnte es natürlich umschreiben: *... bei der Gesperr und Feder gebrochen sind ...*

Comment: Und *mit gebrochenen Gesperr und Feder*? (als Analogon zu: *Das Gesperr und die Feder **sind** gebrochen*)

Comment: @Bart...Hab ich gemeint aber leider nicht geschriben. Jetzt ist dies korrigiert worden